# Fourier Computation integral

Tags: fourier-analysis

$$F(w)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-|x|+ix}e^{-iwx} \, dx$$

Need help to compute.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$\dfrac{2}{(k-1)^2+1}$$Try this and it shoudl work.

Answer (score 0):

$$F.T.[e^{-|x|}\cdot e^{ix}] = \dfrac{2}{(k-1)^2+1}$$

Comment: How was this computation done?

Comment: Use this $$\text{F.T.} [e^{-\alpha |x|} ] = \dfrac {2\cdot\alpha }{\alpha ^2 + k ^2}  $$